# How to send an array in a form field using OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I am using OpenAPI 3.0.1 in a YAML file. I am trying to send which should looks like this in Swagger UI:

[image]

But it looks like this:

[image]

I am using `multipart/form-data` as content. This is my OpenAPI definition:

```yaml
  /auth/signup:
    post:
        tags:
            - Auth
        summary: Sign Up
        description: Path that registers the user
        requestBody:
            description: Optional description in *Markdown*
            content:
                multipart/form-data:
                    schema:
                        type: object
                        properties:
                            first_name:
                                type: String
                                example: jhon
                            last_name:
                                type: String
                                example: doyle
                            username:
                                type: String
                                example: jhon
                            password:
                                type: String
                                example: Hola123#
                            languages_spoken:
                                type: Array
                                items:
                                    type: String
                            app_language_id:
                                type: String
                                example: 5fabc4143c7fd90012b554ee
                            email:
                                type: String
                                example: test@gmail.com
                            profile_picture:
                                type: string
                                format: binary
```

**EDIT1:**

I was able to make it looks like in the first picture, but I am receiving the array like this:
[image]

It should looks like this:

```
languages_spoken: [
   hey,
   fsssdd
]
```

How can I make it looks like that?

Comment: Replace `type: String` with `type: string` (lowercase) and `type: Array` with `type: array` (also lowercase). Does this resolve the issue?

Comment: Yeah, it solved, but the other problem is that I am receiving the data how I am explaining in EDIT1